# Add custom information to text citations with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I've come across a case now where I need to refer to items in my bibliography as well as to something someone has told me personally. I would like that text citation to look something like this:

> I know from books and people I have talked to that George Harrison played the guitar in the Beatles (Lennon 1972, pp. 48 sqq.; Starkey 1994, pp. 103 sqq; Paul McCartney, p.c.).

The "Paul McCartney, p.c." part needs to be custom added when needed. How should I do this with `biblatex`? Below a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Who did what in the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1972"}
@book{starkey1994,
    AUTHOR = "Richard Starkey",
    TITLE = "I'm the drummer",
    YEAR = "1994"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
I know from books and people I have talked to that George Harrison played the guitar in the Beatles \parencites[48\psqq]{lennon1972}[103\psqq]{starkey1994}[Paul McCartney p.c.]{}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plural form of the various citation commands, namely `\cites`, `\Cites`, `\parecites`, `\Parecites`, `\footcites`, `\footcitestext`, `\smartcites`, `\Smartcites`, `\textcites`, `\Textcites`, `\supercites`, `\autocites`, and `\Autocites` all take the same basic form (see §. 3.7.3 in the manual):

```
\cites(<pre>)(<post>)[<pre>][<post>]{<key>}...[<pre>][<post>]{<key>}
```

The `(<pre>)(<post>)` are sort of 'global' arguments that precede or follow the entire citation list.  Thus one could use:

```
\parencites(Paul McCartney p.c.)[48\psqq]{lennon1972}[103\psqq]{starkey1994}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
\parencites()(Paul McCartney p.c.)[48\psqq]{lennon1972}[103\psqq]{starkey1994}
```

If one wants only a global pre-note, then you need to supply an empty post-note

```
\parencites(Paul McCartney p.c.;)()[48\psqq]{lennon1972}[103\psqq]{starkey1994}
```